# Read each cell data of a custom Datagrid - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagridview, datagrid

I've defined a custom data-grid whose columns are made up of text-boxes, combo-boxes, and buttons. I've also populated the data on each combo-box by using XAML Binding. Now, I'd like to read the of each selected combobox value and textbox value from the data-grid. But I don't find any way to read it. I've researched on forums and find solutions related to DataGridView but not much for DataGrid. Here's my sample code where I'm defining the custom data-grid and how I'm populating the data in it.

```
public class Data
{

    public List<string> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; }
    public List<string> ActionType { get; set; }


    public Data()
    {
        this.Disciplines = new List<string>
        {
            "Architecture", "Mechanical", "Structure"
        };

        this.Members = new List<string>
        {
            "Ali", "Mubashar", "Muffassir", "Nitin"
        };

        this.ActionType = new List<string>
        {
            "Take Action",
            "For Information"
        };




    }
}
```

---

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    datagrid_additionalinfo.Items.Add(new Data());


}
```

---

```
<DataGrid  Name="datagrid_additionalinfo" Margin="20,0,20,0" 
                   IsReadOnly="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="True" 
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" >


            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment"  Width="*" MinWidth="130">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="235"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Discipline"   Width="100" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Members"  Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action Type"  Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionType}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>


  </DataGrid>
```

Here's how the custom data-grid will look like :
Would appreciate any help. Thank you

[image: Custom Data-Grid WPF]

Comment: Just add "SelectedItem" property as Binding to your code.

Comment: Hi Urgur, I tried but I'm getting the 'null' value on selected item property. Any workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have attached the clean code using ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to a collection property `public List<string> Disciplines { get; set; }` declare a property for selected item

```
public string SelectedDiscipline { get; set; }
```

and bind it to ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Width="200" 
          SelectedIndex="0"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDiscipline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}"/>
```

and do the same for other properties

this way you can access all values without working with DataGridRow cells directly

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks for sharing the possibility. I tried your solution,  I'm not sure why I'm getting the 'null' value on 'selectedDiscipline'. Any workaround?

Comment: initial value for string property is `null`. it is possible to initialize it with some value from collection in a viewmodel. adding `SelectedIndex="0"` select first item. also try add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to ensure that property update happens immediately

Comment: Hi Ash, I tried SelectedIndex="0" but still I'm getting the null value. Also,  where do we need to change the property of UpdateSourceTrigger because I didn't find its name anywhere..

Comment: Thanks Ash, it worked. I missed the UpdateSourceTrigger property. Many thanks. you've saved my work day ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that there is basic understanding problem here. You mix behind code with MVVM structure. Instead of that code;

```
datagrid_additionalinfo.Items.Add(new Data());
```

try to use use `ObservableCollection<Data>` as ItemSource for the DataGrid in your ViewModel. Use your ViewModel as DataContext for your View. After that you can bind the SelectedItems.

Here is the code;

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridComboBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <DataGrid  Name="datagrid_additionalinfo" Margin="20,0,20,0" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataRow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   IsReadOnly="False" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="True" 
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"  >


            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Comment"  Width="*" MinWidth="130">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="235"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Discipline"   Width="100" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}" 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedDisipline, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Members"  Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action Type"  Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ActionType}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>


        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); 
        }
    }


**MainWindowViewModel**

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

...

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private ObservableCollection<Data> m_DataItems;

        public ObservableCollection<Data> DataItems
        {
            get { return m_DataItems; }
            set { m_DataItems = value; }
        }


        private Data m_SelectedDataRow;
        public Data SelectedDataRow
        {
            get { return m_SelectedDataRow; }
            set { m_SelectedDataRow = value; }
        }


        private string m_SelectedDisipline;
        public string SelectedDisipline
        {
            get { return m_SelectedDisipline; }
            set { m_SelectedDisipline = value; }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            m_DataItems = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

            //Fill Items 
            Data data; 
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                data = new Data();
                m_DataItems.Add(data);
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Ugur, still not able to get the values from the cell. I edited the code as you've said. Any other workaround?

Comment: Thanks Ugur for sharing the solution. Really appreciate your support. However, the above solution provided by Ash also worked. I'll dig your code later tonight. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. But be carefull, quick dirty solutions can save the day, but in the end there might be need a better solution using full MVVM pattern.